# what is the command to make the "cut" in one big molecule?

Tags: symbols, chemfig, chemistry

what the command to make the  zigzag at the cut point in one  big molecule?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    
    \chemfig{*6(---(--[:120,,,,decorate,decoration=snake])---)}
    \chemfig{*6(---(-(-[:-45,,,,decorate,decoration=snake])-[:120,,,,decorate,decoration=snake])---)}

\chemfig{*6(-N(-(-[:0,0.7,,,decorate,decoration=snake])-[:180,0.7,,,decorate,decoration=snake])-=(-(=[:90]O)-[:-35]NH_2)-(<[:135]H)(<:[:45]H)-=)}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much